# Counting the total number of one level in R with missing data

Tags: r, count

I have a vector:

```
a<-c("Yes","No","No","Yes",NA)
```

I want to count how many Yes'es there are:

```
length(a[a=="Yes"])
```

Why is the answer 3?  How can I obtain the correct answer?

Comment: That's because R doesn't know how to treat the `NA` so it outputs it by default. So you'll have to decide for it. Try `length(na.omit(a[a=="Yes"]))` or `length(a[!is.na(a) & a=="Yes"])` or `sum(grepl("Yes", a))`

Answer (score 3):

Look at the intermediate steps:

```
a<-c("Yes","No","No","Yes",NA)
length(a[a=="Yes"])
[1] 3
a=="Yes"
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA
a[a=="Yes"]
[1] "Yes" "Yes" NA
```

This shows why you get 3 as the answer; NA can't be cast to either a true or false value, R always evaluates it as NA. A simple way to get the correct answer is

```
sum(na.omit(a=="Yes"))
[1] 2
```

Comment: Or `sum(a=="Yes",na.rm=TRUE)`